# custom histnorm in plotly.express density_heatmap

Tags: python, plotly, heatmap

I am trying to create a heatmap, where all fields for one x-position should sum up to 100. So the density is not calculated for the complete graph (like `histnorm=probability` would do), but only for the fields with the same x-position.
[[image: example heatmap]
Given the example above I want the "heat" to be evenly distributed over all x-positions (e.g. all fields with x=5 combined should have the same heat as all fields with x=3).

I could not find any information in the documentation [here](https://plot.ly/python-api-reference/generated/plotly.express.density_heatmap.html).

Thank you for your help and have a great start in the new year

Sören

Comment: Could you please elaborate on what you are trying to get? Do you have an example?

Comment: I tried to elaborate a little more and added an example in the question.

Comment: Thank you Sören! I guess the question is not about plotting itself. I would think about how to calculate data values so it shall fit your requirements about "heat distribution".

Comment: True, I hoped that there would be a "standard" way to deal with this. I am not sure how to start.

Comment: I would focus to the dataset. Think in detail about what you mean by "heat distribution". It is probably about actual values distribution. So you shall to figure our what's the criteria to data per X (X=0, X=1 so on).